# Why I use frontend-maven-plugin build vue have an empty error

Tags: node.js, npm, maven-plugin, frontend-maven-plugin

I use frontend-maven-plugin to build my spring boot program,but I have an error.
Error Message:

```
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) @ monitor-admin ---
[INFO] Node v10.16.0 is already installed.
[INFO] NPM 6.9.0 is already installed.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:npm (npm install) @ monitor-admin ---
[INFO] Running 'npm install' in /Users/xxx/Program/xxx/monitor-ui
[WARNING] npm WARN eslint-loader@2.2.1 requires a peer of eslint@>=1.6.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
[WARNING] npm WARN sass-loader@10.1.0 requires a peer of node-sass@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
[WARNING] npm WARN sass-loader@10.1.0 requires a peer of fibers@>= 3.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
[ERROR] 
[INFO] up to date in 4.55s
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:npm (npm run build) @ monitor-admin ---
[INFO] Running 'npm run build:qa' in /Users/xxx/Program/xxx/monitor-ui
[INFO] 
[INFO] > monitor@1.0.0 build:qa /Users/xxx/Program/xxx/monitor-ui
[INFO] > vue-cli-service build --mode qa
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[ERROR] -  Building for qa...
[INFO]  WARNING  Compiled with 2 warnings5:30:05 PM
[INFO] 
[INFO]  warning  
[INFO]
```

My pom:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>${vue.project.root}</workingDirectory>
                    <downloadRoot>http://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/node/</downloadRoot>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v10.16.0</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>6.9.0</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Install all project dependencies -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!-- optional: default phase is "generate-resources" -->
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <!-- Optional configuration which provides for running any npm command -->
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Build and minify static files -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build:${activatedProperties}</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

The final build was successful.Program also can run.I don't know why this error occurred.All log flows look normal.The error has no details, only one [error].Thank you for your help

Comment: I doubt those are actually errors.  It's probably just a process that maven is spawning, which is writing to stderr.  Maven interprets that as an error ocurring but it's really not.

Comment: Is there any way not to output this error log

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading `frontend-maven-plugin` **from** `1.6` **to** `1.10.0` worked for me

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```